# boolean algebra simplification

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

a) $(\lnot(P \land Q)) \lor (Q \land R)$

b) $(P \lor Q) \land \lnot(Q)$

How do I simplify these 2 expression?

Comment: Can you do something about the TeX?

Comment: An equation is something with an equals sign. You have written two formulas, not two equations.

Comment: You can use DeMorgan's so that all the connections are "AND"s or "OR"s...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can often simplify boolean propositions by fiddling around with the algebra.

Sometimes it helps to push in all negations to bring the formula to [negation normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form). This means using de Morgan's law repeatedly until all negation signs are directly in front of literals:

$\neg (P\wedge Q) \vee (Q\wedge R) = \neg P\vee \neg Q \vee (Q\wedge R)$ [de Morgan's]

The next step you should do is either to bring the formula to [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form). Both of these forms only have to "layers" of nesting in terms of bracketing, provided you write $A \wedge (B \wedge C)$ as $A \wedge B \wedge C$, and similarly also don't write brackets in chains of disjunctions (i.e. "$\vee$"s) . To bring a formula to disjunctive normal form, you have to push in $\wedge$ using the law $A \wedge ( B \vee C) = (A \wedge B) \vee (A \wedge C)$. As it happens, we've already reached disjunctive normal form in the above formula.

From here, there are many ways to continue. In the above example, the formula is clearly true if $\neg P$ or $\neg Q$ are true. Then what happens if $P$ and $Q$ are true? Well, in that case, you must have $Q \wedge R$ true, and we're already assuming $Q$ is true, it's enough that $R$ is true. So, a simplified version of your formula is

$\neg P\vee \neg Q \vee R$.

In your second formula, considering the different possible values of $Q$ will also help you out.

If you want to be more systematic in your simplifications, then a good approach is to use [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_mapping). These are a very human-friendly way of simplifying formulas with up to four variables, but after that the maps get very unwieldy.

If you need to cope with more variables in a systematic way, you can use the [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

You don't have to put your formula in disjunctive normal form to use Karnaugh maps or the Quine-McCluskey algorithm, you just have to compute the truth table for your formula.

Comment: You're right, I did have a mistake - have deleted it now!

Comment: The expression $\lnot P\lor\lnot Q\lor(Q\land R)$ is already in disjunctive normal form.

Comment: @Asaf, yup, hence "As it happens, we've already reached disjunctive normal form in the above formula.".

Comment: D'oh, I did not see that :-)

Comment: @its-ok-in-theory hi, why it is $ \lnot Q \land Q $ will give $ \lnot Q $ back ?

Comment: @liangteh, that's not quite what happens. One way to understand it is to do the following manipulation: $\neg Q \vee (Q\wedge R) =  (\neg Q \vee Q)\wedge(\neg Q \vee R) = T \wedge (\neg Q \vee R) = \neg Q \vee R.$

Answer (score 5):

a) 
1. $(\lnot(P \land Q)) \lor (Q \land R)$
2. $(\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \lor (Q\land R)$
3. $((\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \lor Q) \land ((\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \lor R)$
4. $(\lnot P \lor (\lnot Q \lor Q)) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor R)$
5. $(\lnot P \lor True) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor R)$
6. $(True ) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor R)$
7. $\lnot P \lor \lnot Q \lor R\qquad$ (Simplified normal disjunctive form)

Note: By DeMorgan's, (7) is equivalent to $\lnot(P \land Q) \lor R$

b) 
1.  $(P \lor Q) \land \lnot(Q)$ 
2.  $(P \land \lnot Q) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q)$
3.  $(P \land \lnot Q) \lor (False)$ 
4.  $(P \land \lnot Q)\qquad$ (simplified in normal disjunctive form)

Can you understand how to move from one step to the next? Essentially, I am simply applying "distribution":
e.g. $(a \lor b) \land c \equiv (a \land c) \lor (b \land c)$ 
also $a \lor (b \land c) \equiv (a \lor b) \land (a \lor c)$ 
and I've used DeMorgan's in the first simplifications.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, try writing $\lnot (P \land Q)$ using an "or" instead of an "and" - you should know a rule to convert between the two.

For the second, what can you say about P, given you know that Q is false?

Comment: for the second one 

$ (x')' = x $  therefore
$ (P \lor Q) $

Comment: why $(\lnot(P \land Q)) \lor (Q \land R)$ becomes $(\lnot(P \land Q)) \lor R$